# How can I export all bash variables declared in a file as environment variables?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, export

Let us say I have a txt file `vars.txt` like this.

```
VAR1=32
VAR2=47
VAR3=78
```

Now if I simply do `source vars.txt`, these variables won't be exported as environment variables because I didn't prefix them with `export`.

So, my question is, is there a way to export all those variables without having to prefix them with export in the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: `set -a`

From [`help set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

> Options:
>         -a    Mark variables which are modified or created for export.

To export every variable in your file you would do

```
set -a
source yourFile
set +a
```